# Get the first Friday of the Quarter of Today's Date

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to get the first Friday of the quarter of today's date or any given date. Let's say the date is 12/06/2020, which falls to the 2nd quarter of the year. I should be able to get the first Friday of the 2nd Quarter and that should be April 3rd.

I was only been able to get the quarter of a given date, which you can see in the code below. Been stuck here for a while. Thanks in advance.

`quarter = Int((Month(Now) + 2) / 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that takes a date and returns the first Friday of the quarter:

```
Function FirstFridayOfTheQuarter(MyDate As Date) As Date

    Dim FirstDayOfTheQuarter As Date
    FirstDayOfTheQuarter = DateSerial(Year(MyDate), Int((Month(MyDate) - 1) / 3) * 3 + 1, 1)
    FirstFridayOfTheQuarter = DateAdd("d", (13 - Weekday(FirstDayOfTheQuarter)) Mod 7, FirstDayOfTheQuarter)

End Function
```

This function is taking advantage of the `Weekday` function that returns:

```
1 for a Sunday
2 for a Monday
3 for a Tuesday
4 for a Wednesday
5 for a Thursday
6 for a Friday
7 for a Saturday
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your response. I tried the code for the year 2020, and it works fine. But when I tried it for the year 2019, i tried to get the first friday of Q1 and got 03/01/2020 which is supposed to be 04/01/2019. also when i tried to use it with year 2022, I got the error that says: Invalid procedure call or argument. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: When I run `FirstFridayOfTheQuarter(DateSerial(2019,1,1))` I get 2019-01-04 as well.

Comment: Hi I didn't saw that you edited your answer. now it's working. but I tried it with the date "21/03/2022" and got the answer 31/12/2021. the correct date should be 7/1/2022

Comment: Hum, seems like the behavior of the Mod operator is different for negative numbers than the Excel Mod function. Changing the 6 for a 13 will fix this (I've edited the answer).

Comment: Wow now everything works fine. Appreciate your answer. I'm really a beginner using vba/macro. Hopefully one day, I'll be able to code like you and give answer to other's questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a non VBA solution:

[image]

My formula is:

```
=CEILING(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(A1);ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3;0)+(ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3;0)-1)*2;1);-1)-5;7)+6
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer and sorry for the very late reply. I tried using my formula, and there is a prompt that appears that says that there's a problem with the formula. I'm not sure what's causing the problem. Thanks